# Mobile Safari iPhone Development - Multiple buttons in a row

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, mobile-website, dashcode

I'm an iPhone developer, but new to web development. I've done some basic HTML websites and made one in iWeb as well. I'm trying to branch out to mobile web development now, so I checked out Dashcode.

Anyway, I'm trying to put a Call Button, Mail Button, and Map Button in horizontal alignment. I realize that I can add a Column Layout and have two buttons in a row, but that's the most I've gotten.

Any ideas? Thanks!
Thomas

Edit: I still haven't figured this out yet. I was given advice about a fixed position button bar, but I am not sure how to implement it. I've been looking at code, but haven't gotten it yet. Still trying though. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i do usually is to select the element you can't align horizontally and then go to the inspector -> dimension tab and in disposition you select fixed absolute.
This should work but beware because if you've the intention to change element's place dynamically you may have some surprise...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [something like this](http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/).

A fixed position button bar is created with several buttons side by side.

/Mogens

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. But I don't see how this helps. Maybe it's because I am new to web dev, but I do not get how this corresponds with my question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The example shows how to get icons aligned horizontally, so just forget about the fixed position bar, and look at the CSS for the icons and the UL and LI tags. And google everything you don't understand in the CSS.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your help!